# hibernate mapping for shared model

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

There are 3 entity classes - Item, Seller, Comment. Where,

```
Item 1 --- * Comment, and Seller 1 --- * Comment
```

How can I map the class with JPA/Hibernate annotation without adding addition tables?

The tables structure are:

```
Item(id, description)
Seller(id, name)
Comment(id, entityType, entityKey, message)
```

where entityType is ITEM or SELLER, the entityKey is either item.id or seller.id .

Right now, I have something like the following:

**Update: OneToMany side is OK now, still need to figure out how to make it works in the ManyToOne side.**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item_tb")
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    *** @OneToMany
    *** @JoinColumn(name = "entityKey")
    *** @Where(clause = "entityType = 'ITEM'")
    private List<Comment> comments;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "seller_tb")
public class Seller {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    *** @OneToMany
    *** @JoinColumn(name = "entityKey")
    *** @Where(clause = "entityType = 'SELLER'")
    private List<Comment> comments;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "comment_tb")
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "entityType")
    private String entityType;

    @Column(name = "entityKey")
    private Integer entityKey;

    @Column(name = "message")
    private String message;

    @ManyToOne
    ...
    private Item item;

    @ManyToOne
    ...
    private Seller seller;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities I can think of:

[1] Use Hibernate's @Where annotation on each of the @OneToMany mappings. This can be used to restrict the comments to the appropriate type for each collection.

[2] Use Hibernate's inheritance features  (table per class hierarchy for the schema as it is). Create two entities SellerComment and ItemComment mapped to the same table and using a discrimiator column (entityType). The the @OneToOmany collections to the relevant types:

There may be issues with [2] which will require use of the @ForceDiscriminator annotation. The approch is outline here: http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2009/08/26/hibernate-why-should-i-force-discriminator/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can resolve part of the problem using [1]. As there are a lot of entities having Comment, can't add classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use One to Many bidirectional without join table, meaning the Comment table would have a foreign key pointing to the item table. Your relationship would look like

```
Item
..............
@OneToMany(mappedBy="item")    
private List<Comment> comments;


Comment
...............
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="item_id")
private Item item;
```

In your code you must set both sides of relations correctly.

Comment: I cannot do so. Because there is no FK in the comment table, and it is shared by the seller and item.